# Google chrome/ Internet explorer do not accept self signed, Firefox does

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, firefox, ssl-certificate

I have created a Self Signed certificate which i use for security purposes. When i try to use it on Firefox i have no problems using it.
On firefox i get this error, which allows me to continue:

[image]

But, in Google Chrome i can not continue to do this. I get the following error:

[image]

What could i be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easiest Option!**

Simply paste this in your chrome:

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
```

You should see highlighted text saying: Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost

Click Enable.

**Note:** use this only in your testing environment

You can also follow steps followed [here](http://www.robpeck.com/2010/10/google-chrome-mac-os-x-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates/#.V2z4wvl96Ch) if you don't want to simply allow invalid certificate

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the address the site is being served up as is the same as the certificate? I had the same problems with Chrome and a self-signed cert, but in the end I found it was just incredibly picky about the validation of the domain name on the cert (as it should be).

Chrome doesn't have it's own cert store and uses Window's own. However Chrome provides no way to import certs into the store so you should add them via IE instead.